# Choice of statistical test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, experiment-design

I would need some help in order to understand which statistical tests apply for my experimental design.

I want to compare two groups of participants in an experimental protocol in which the linguistic items (written words to be read) are presented according to two different categorical independent variables (see below).

My independent variables:

- Group variable (G): two groups of participants to be compared (two modalities: G1 or G2)
- Categorical variable (A): grammatical category of the item to be read (two modalities: A1 or A2)
- Categorical variable (B): gender of the item to be read (two modalities: B1 or B2)

My dependent variables:

- Binary variable X having outcome 1 or 0 for a correct vs. incorrect item
- Continuous variable Y (difference between time of reading of the item compared to average reading time of the participant)
- Continuous variable Z (difference between number of pauses during the reading of the item compared to average number of pauses of the participant during reading)

I should probably specify that, since I compare the performance of two different groups, my study design is between-subjects, but in each group participants read all the items in all the experimental conditions.

There is a high chance that my data will contain missing values, so I would prefer a model which models that. Moreover, based on past experience, I would like to have a model not based on the normality assumption.

It is also worth noting that the "success" variable X is supposed to contain many more 1s than 0s (errors should not be systematic in neither of the two groups, but I expect that there will be more errors in one of the two groups).

Could you please help me to understand which statistical tests I should apply? I apologize in advance for the long post.

Comment: It seems this may be $3\times 3 = 9$ questions instead of one. Please begin by picking **one** situation: How many subjects? How many groups (2?) Show sample data for a few subjects, with explanation. Say what comparison you want to make with your statistical test.

Comment: Are the subjects randomized to groups? More or less, how many subjects? ...